# Data Not Submitting to Database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

I'm making a contact page but the form data is not saving to the database. What's the solution?

**ContactController.php**

```php
public function contact()
{
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $data = $request->all();
    }
    $contact = new Contact;
    $contact->name = $data['contact_name'];
    $contact->email = $data['contact_email'];
    $contact->subject = $data['contact_subject'];
    $contact->body = $data['description'];
    $category->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 
        'Your message has been sent successfully');
}
```

**contact.blade.php**

```php
<form action="{{ url('/contact') }}" id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form row" name="contact-form" method="post">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <input type="text" name="contact_subject" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Subject">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <textarea name="description" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
     </div>                        
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit">
     </div>
</form>
```

**Routes**:

```php
Route::get('contact', function(){
    return view('contact');
});

Route::post('contact', function(){
    return view('contact');
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your `App\Contact` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$contact->save();` not `$category->save();` and also remove the if statement (for now): `if($request->isMethod('post')) {`

Your route should be:

```
Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@contact')->name('contact');
```

Comment: thnx but still same issue

Comment: When you try to see the output, ex: dd($data), what is shown? Also, remove: $request->isMethod('POST').